# Installing pymsql on windows 8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pymssql

I've installed Python 3.6.4 on Windows 8.1 64-bit.
I have it on system environment variables path as:

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6
```

The command `python` works in any location with command line so the path works.

**Here's the problem:**

As I type `pip install pymssql` in Powershell I get the following error message:

```
Command "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c 

"import setuptools, tokenize;__file__=
'C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-20pjis7d\\pymssql\\setup.py';

f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f
.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))"

install --record C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-myeuf_lm-record\install-record.txt 
--single-version-externally-managed --compile" 
failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-20pjis7d\pymssql\
```

Can't find anything with that error message with Google search.

Any ideas what might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to use `virtualenv` rather than installing into your global environment. `virtualenv` will also automatically pull in the latest setuptools.

```
pip install virtualenv
virutalenv my_venv
source my_venv/bin/activate
pip install pymysql
```

Also make sure that you meet the installation requirements outlined here: http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html

You may need to install MySQL server or MariaDB

Comment: This was great. Following those instructions got me the environment with everything I need.